# Relation between characterstic and cardinality of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I am studying Galois Theory from Hungerford's book and while studying lemma on page 280 ( lemma 5.5).

> Does there exists a field which is not finite but characterstic is finite?

This question arised in my mind as I was reading lemma5.5 as here if F is finite, then $\phi$ is an automorohism otherwise monomorphism but in both cases it has cardinality p.
[image]

> I think there doesn't exist ( if isomorphism of elements are considered)but why as there would be only {0,1,..., p-1} elements(distinct) due to characterstic being p, but isomorphisms of elements are not concerened then I thing there will exist.

So, should isomorphism be considered?

Comment: I'm confused: what's the question **exactly**? Does there exist an infinite field with finite characteristic? Yes, there are infinit examples...or "should isomorphism be considered"? This last I don't understand it...What does "isomorphism of elements" mean, anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the algebraic closure of a finite field.

Any field has an algebraic closure, on one hand.  On the other, any algebraically closed field is infinite.

This gives a whole host of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Take  $\mathbb{F}_{p} (t) $ denoted for all rational functions with coefficients in the field $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ and $p$ is prime.

Comment: That is not a field...Perhaps you meant $\;\Bbb Z_p(x)\;$ ?

Comment: You want the function field....

Comment: @DonAntonio it's not the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[x]$ to which I indicated,, I did some edits for better understanding

Comment: @Mummy the turkey hmmm

Comment: @Alearner The notation you use is internationally used fo the ring of polynomials. The **field** of rational functions is denoted as I wrote above. That's what confuses in your post.

Comment: @Alearner Changing $\;x\;$ to $\;t\;$ doesn't me that notation correct...It **must** be $\;(x)\;$ ...or $\;(t)\;$ , if you prefer. And I don't know what "worldwide book" you mean...or what what "worldwide book" even means.

Comment: @DonAntonio ok, as you say.

Comment: Yeah, as @DonAntonio says, by $k[t]$ we always mean the polynomial ring which never a field if $t$ is transcendental over $k$.